# Obtener los valores de los input name con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una aplicacion con varios checkboxes, y este codigo con **Jquery**:

```
var checkboxes = $(".borrar_contacto");
console.log(checkboxes);
```

Y este con **JavaScript**:

```
var checkboxes2 = document.getElementsByClassName("borrar_contacto");
console.log(checkboxes2);
```

En console.log no me muestran los mismos resultados. Con Jquery me muestra lo siguiente:

```
[input.borrar_contacto, input.borrar_contacto, 
input.borrar_contacto, input.borrar_contacto, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]]
```

Y con JavaScript lo siguiente:

```
[input.borrar_contacto, input.borrar_contacto, 
input.borrar_contacto, input.borrar_contacto, 
10: undefined, 11: undefined, 12: undefined, 13: undefined]
```

Con JavaScript me muestra en la lista, los valores de los input name, pero con Jquery no. Como puedo hacer que me muestre exactamente lo mismo con Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- El método [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) retorna un objecto similar a un `array` ([`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) de los elementos hijos que tengan todos los nombres de clase indicados.
- El método [`$([selector])`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) devuelve un `jQuery object` que contiene una colección de elementos del `DOM`.

> Como puedo hacer que me muestre exactamente lo mismo con Jquery?

Para que poder obtener exactamente lo mismo con `jQuery`, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Convertir el `HTMLCollection` a `array`, haciendo uso del método [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice)
- Convertir el `jQuery object` a `array`, haciendo uso del método [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/)

Así por ejemplo:

```js
var checkboxes2 = document.getElementsByClassName("borrar_contacto");
// Convertimos el HTMLCollection a array
console.log([].slice.call(checkboxes2));

var checkboxes = $(".borrar_contacto");
// Convertimos el jQuery object a array
console.log(checkboxes.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="borrar_contacto" value="1" />Contacto 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="borrar_contacto" value="2" />Contacto 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="borrar_contacto" value="3" />Contacto 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="borrar_contacto" value="4" />Contacto 4</label>
```

Comment: Yo por lo que veo en JS me retorna los valores de los name porque como bien decis, retorna un array de tipo HTMLCollection, no hay forma que con Jquery retorne ese array? Recien probé en Jquery con .toArray y no me funcionó. No me muestran los valores de los name como con JS.

Comment: @fedR, ¿por que quieres usar `jQuery` para hacer algo que puedes hacerlo sin él? Realmente no entiendo que quieres decir con "_No me muestran los valores de los name como con JS_"

Comment: Disculpame es que estoy haciendo una aplicación con ajax y esta todo con Jquery y no quiero mezclarlo con JavaScript, pero si no hay problema  de mezclar lo dejo así, no se si esta bien o no. El problema es que con Jquery usando el selector me esta tirando un error y con JS funciona correctamente con esa línea. Pienso que el problema está ahí.

Comment: @fedR, [Edita tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/45460/edit) y agrega: el `script` que te genera error y el error que recibes. Esto es para poder entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Ahí lo pude solucionar!!! Habia creado la variable con el selector `var checkboxes = $(".borrar_contacto");` arriba de todo, y cuando lo tenia que usar viarias veces abajo, se ve que la variable se pisaba o algo por el estilo, con ponerle solo `$(".borrar_contacto")` cuando lo tenia que usar de nuevo lo pude solucionar. Muchas gracias @Marcos Gallardo.

Answer (score 2):

Obtener el valor del atributo 'name' de los inputs:

```
$('.borrar_contacto').attr('name');
```

Obtener el valor que tiene introducido el input (parámetro value):

```
$('.borrar_contacto').val();
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Si tus inputs tienen una clase asignada llamada "borrar_contacto" puedes usar:

```
$('.borrar_contacto').each(function(){
         console.log($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para Obtener los valores de los input name con Jquery puedes usar el siguiente trozo de código de jquery:

```
$("input[name='borrar_contacto']").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Con este código obtienes todos los valores de los `inputs` con el nombre `borrar_contacto`.

Answer (score 0):

para cojer el valor de un input mediante el

```
$("[name='id']").attr("value");
```